# Offset for mmap() must be page aligned

Tags: c, linux, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, mmap

I was going through the manual of the mmap function and came across this line:

```
pa_offset = offset & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
/* offset for mmap() must be page aligned */
```

I think I understand what this line does. It gets the page size and makes sure that pa_offset is either zero or a multiple of the page size (4096 here). But I do not understand how. I know what the bitwise operators do, but is it possible to explain how exactly this is being achieved?

Comment: Assuming the page size is a power of two, then then one less than the page-size will have all bits set, until the bit that represents the power of two corresponding to the page size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't notice the power of two